# Regular expression to validate '/' in URL

Tags: regex, url, go

I am writing a web application in golang. I am using regular expression to validate the URL. But I am not able to include '/' in the URL validation.

```
var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/(home|about)/(|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$")
```

The above URL takes '/home/', '/about/' but could not make for '/'.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not adding that case as an alternative:

```
"^/$|(/(home|about)/(|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want optional groups:

```
"^/(home|about)?(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$"
```

[Demonstration](https://play.golang.org/p/l-j3OBm7FZ)